# number of RAID levels that a single controller can support

Tags: raid, configuration

looking for having 3 volumes in RAID1 and RAID5. does a single RAID controller PERC 6i on my DEll PE 2900 manage there volumes/disks in RAID-1, RAID-1, RAID-5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the PERC 6i will support it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In general, a single RAID controller will be able to support multiple volumes, each using a different RAID type.  Seeing as the Dell PE 2900 has 10 HDD bays, you should have no problem doing what you suggested.

Comment: Sorry for the redundant answer. wolfgangsz beat me to the punch.